# Is it possible to use characters instead of a position in a substring function?

Tags: sql, mysql, phpmyadmin

is it possible to use characters instead of a position in a substring function?

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(title,2) FROM table
```

puts out every title starting with the second position.

Now I want to cut the output after a space. The space positions varies.
Is it realiseable?

I tried sth. like

```
SUBSTRING(title,2,LOCATE('',title))
```

,but for some reason the output was empty.

Thank you in advance.
Soloco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SUBSTRING_INDEX` for that:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(title, ' ', 1) FROM table
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('hello world', ' ', 1) # gives you 'hello'
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.htm

Answer (score 0):

In your LOCATE statement, you are searching for an empty string `''` instead of a space `' '`

Add a space character.

What you are doing will fetch the string from its second character to the first occurrence of a space character. Is this really what you want to do? What if the the first or second character are space characters?

Comment: Indeed it's specific. But that's exactly what I want to do. The space hint was very good though. Thanks for that. Unfortunately the output still contains the first letter of some text...

Comment: Ah, by changing the string from its first character the output is ok. Well, I'll stick the rest in my phpscript. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
SUBSTRING(title,2,charindex('',title)-1)
```

This would cut the string just before the space in the title